# WINAPI methods with nonzero return value at success

Tags: c++, winapi

For a lot of WINAPI methods, the return value is either 0 (failure) or nonzero (success). For example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682565(v=vs.85).aspx

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
> If the function fails, the return value is zero.

My question is, for such a method, is it correct to test the return value with `TRUE` (which is a `BOOL` value equal to 1)? Or is it more correct to test if the return value is `!FALSE` instead?

Another nonrelated question is, when the return value is non-zero, what exactly is it? Can it be any value or from a set of values?

Comment: It says nonzero. In no way does that mean `TRUE`.

Comment: If the doc says that a non-zero return means 'OK', then that is all you know - if the different values meant anything that could be relied-upon then it would be documented - or at least if it is not documented you should ignore this possibility.

Comment: I'm almost always test the return value as `if(!SomeFunction())`

Comment: Beware of this one: some WINAPI methods return 0 for failure, others return 0 for success.  It would be clearer to check for 0 instead of confusing everyone with FALSE.  If you are using the API and the interface requires a BOOL result, then by all means use TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: so to sum up I should check it as `!FALSE`?

Comment: To sum up, you should return false if the value is 0, true otherwise.

Comment: Imo, `TRUE` and `FALSE` shouldn't really even come into play. `if (!SomeFunction())` is clearer as I see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the method you mentioned is:

```
BOOL WINAPI DeleteTimerQueue(_In_ HANDLE TimerQueue);
```

In the Windows headers the type **`BOOL`** is defined as an **`int`**. This is for historical reasons, since in the days before C99 there was no **`bool`** type that we are now familiar with, and WinAPI have kept using the BOOL definition for many of the methods introduced later on.

Further, the Windows headers look very similar to this, if we take the liberty to simplify a bit,

```
typedef int   BOOL
#define FALSE 0  // < note that #define <number> introduces an integer constant
#define TRUE  1
```

Thus your question can be interpreted as whether testing for `!<integer>` is equivalent to testing against a boolean value. The answer is yes, with C++ testing `!0 == true` and `!n == false` for any integral `n > 0`.

> Another nonrelated question is, when the return value is non-zero, what exactly is it? Can it be any value or from a set of values?

It will be different for different WinAPI methods. Generally it can be any value, but since the return type is conceptually a boolean, it is okay to test it as a boolean.

> so to sum up I should check it as …

The idiomatic way to check is:

```
if(!DeleteTimerQueue(handle)) {
    /* handle the error case */
    /* call GetLastError() where applicable */
}
/* otherwise proceed, the call succeeded */
```